# Spring Data MongoDB - no signature of method is applicable for argument types

Tags: mongodb, groovy, spring-data-mongodb

I had a certain method that called `MongoOperations.find(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)`, and returned a `List<T>` as expected. I want to change the method to `stream()`, in case the number of returned objects from the query is exceptionally large. According to [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#stream-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-), there should be an identical signature for `stream()`, but when I try to call the function with a `collectionName`, I get an error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.stream() is applicable for argument types: (org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String)

When I remove the `collectionName`, it runs without error. Could this be an issue of Spring Data versions? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @tim_yates, at this point that's a little problematic. But I honestly don't think the code would give you more information, it's all in the question.

Comment: What version of spring mongo db are you on ? The method that takes collection name is added in 1.10 version. More details here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1431

Comment: @Veeram, indeed it was a version issue. Updating to 1.10 solved the problem. If you'd like, you can add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloaded `stream` method which takes `collection name` as an argument  in `MongoOperations` is added in Mongo Spring `1.10` version.

The change is covered as part of the ticket. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1431